# Is $f(x) = O\big(f(x)\big)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, asymptotics

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions and approach some value $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \pm \infty $, they can be expressed as $f(x) = O\big(g(x)\big)$ for $x$ approaching $a$, if there is a constant $c > 0$ such that $\cfrac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)} \leq c$ for every sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \rightarrow  a$.

My textbook gives this example: $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = x^2 +2$, as
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\cfrac{x^2}{x^2+2} = 1 \implies f(x) = O(x^2+2).$$
I am supposed to state the most trivial function $g(x)$ for which this holds true. Logically, this would always be $g(x) = f(x)$. For some reason, this case is never considered in the answer sheet. Is there a reason as to why this case is never considered?

Comment: "I am supposed to state the most trivial function $g(x)$ for which this holds true." Can you elaborate on this more? And what answers are provided on the answer sheet? It is true that people desire to write $f(x)=O(g(x))$ where $g(x)$ is a *simpler* function than $f$. So for instance, it would be desirable to write $x^2+2=O(x^2)$, even if both $x^2+2=O(x^2+2)$ and $x^2=O(x^2+2)$ are also technically true.

Comment: Your definition of $O$ is good for functions with positive values.  I would not say $x^2 = O(-x)$ as $x \to +\infty$, despite $x^2/(-x) \le 1$ for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE!

Well, we have

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} 1 = 1 \leq 1$$

no matter our choice of $a$. So this tells us that

$$f(x) = O(f(x)) \quad \quad (x \to a)$$

for every choice of $a$.

Of course, this is sufficiently simple that many textbooks omit it. Whether or not that's good pedagogy is a different question...

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Great, this was what I thinking too.. Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. If this answered your question, you should mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark button so that other users know how to spend their time.